# Is there any point in making this service asynchronous

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous

I have a WCF service which essentially just does this:

```
public SomeClass SomeMethod(){
  using(var db = new LinqToSqlContext()){
       return db.SomeMethod();
  }
}
```

Client side it has auto generated asynchronous methods but I'm just wondering if there is any benefit to making the service itself use async Tasks? After all the method finishes when it finishes and it could only ever await on a single method.

Comment: We can't answer generic questions on stack overflow. Consider adding specifics or going to programmers.

Comment: I provided an example, and I'm asking if an async approach would benefit the provided example, I don't see how this question can be more specific.

Comment: The problem with this question is that it isn't about programming, it's about architecture - and there does not appear to be a specific issue being questioned about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: probably not.

`async` can help a WCF service scale faster and farther, but if your backend is just a single SQL server (as seems likely from your code), then even synchronous code can probably scale further than your SQL server.

Long answer: you won't know for sure until you do it both ways and run performance tests.

Answer (score 0):

If the method can do multiple tasks independently at the same time, then there might be a performance benefit from using Tasks to run them asynchronously.

Otherwise there's no point (and it may even be a negative effect due to overhead of multi-threading).